# Signup page error

Tags: php

I'm new to PHP and I got this error while trying to create a signup page.

**Notice: Undefined index: remarks in C:\xampp\htdocs\phptest\index.php on line 7**

This is the code of the index.php

```
<form name="reg" action="code_exec.php" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">
<table width="274" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">
        <div align="center">
          <?php 
        $remarks=$_GET['remarks'];
        if ($remarks==null and $remarks=="")
        {
        echo 'Register Here';
        }
        if ($remarks=='success')
        {
        echo 'Registration Success';
        }
        ?>  
        </div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="95"><div align="right">First Name:</div></td>
    <td width="171"><input type="text" name="fname" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><div align="right">Last Name:</div></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="lname" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><div align="right">Gender:</div></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="mname" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><div align="right">Address:</div></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="address" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><div align="right">Contact No.:</div></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="contact" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><div align="right">Picture:</div></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="pic" /></td>
  </tr>
 <tr>
    <td><div align="right">Username:</div></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="username" /></td>
  </tr>
 <tr>
    <td><div align="right">Password:</div></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="password" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><div align="right"></div></td>
    <td><input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</form>
```

May I know which part is wrong ? Everything is running perfectly but the error message pop out in the signup page interface. How do I remove it or is it something wrong with my code ?

Comment: what is your URL? Have you pass any parametter in URL? It can't get any parameter named `ramerks` so pass parameter named `remarks`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because your `$_GET` array, don't have any value with **remarks** key.

I see your form, and I don't see any input with this name. I suppose that you are passing this a querystring variable (yourfile.php?remarks=value)

To avoid the warning, you should test before if **remarks** are in `$_GET`

```
$remarks=isset($_GET['remarks'])?$_GET['remarks']:"";
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `isset()` before get any data from request.

So your code should be

```
$remarks=(isset($_GET['remarks']))?$_GET['remarks']:"";
```

everything will remain as it is.

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
<form name="reg" action="code_exec.php" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">
<table width="274" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">
        <div align="center">
          <?php 

        if (!isset($_GET['remarks']))
        {
        echo 'Register Here';
        }
        if ($remarks=='success')
        {
        echo 'Registration Success';
        }
        ?>  
        </div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="95"><div align="right">First Name:</div></td>
    <td width="171"><input type="text" name="fname" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><div align="right">Last Name:</div></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="lname" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><div align="right">Gender:</div></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="mname" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><div align="right">Address:</div></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="address" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><div align="right">Contact No.:</div></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="contact" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><div align="right">Picture:</div></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="pic" /></td>
  </tr>
 <tr>
    <td><div align="right">Username:</div></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="username" /></td>
  </tr>
 <tr>
    <td><div align="right">Password:</div></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="password" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><div align="right"></div></td>
    <td><input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

when your page loads it doesn't has any Get parameters and that's what **undefined index** means, GET['remarks'] is not declared

you can try something like this instead

```
<?php

    if (!isset($_GET['remarks']) && $remarks=="")
    {
    echo 'Register Here';
    }
    else if($_GET['remarks']=='success')
    {
    echo 'Registration Success';
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code.

```
 <?php 
        $remarks=isset($_GET['remarks'])?$_GET['remarks']:"";
        if ($remarks==null and $remarks=="")
        {
        echo 'Register Here';
        }
        if ($remarks=='success')
        {
        echo 'Registration Success';
        }
        ?>
```